# Why $S^1$ does not deformation retract to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

I tried to use the definition of deformation retract, i.e I have a retract $r:S^1\rightarrow {x_0}$ and I define the homotopy between $id_{S^1}$ and $i\circ r$ via $F(s,t) = tx_0 + (1-t)x$. But geometrically, I know it is not contractible because we cannot "tear" the circle and deform it onto a point. Where my argument gets wrong?

Comment: What happens when $x = -x_0\in S^1$ and $t = 1/2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $F(s,t)$ lives in $\Bbb R^2$ not $S^1$.

Comment: Oh great and clear !